# Css height in percent not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following simple code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Live Feed</title>

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="background-color: #eeaabb; width: 250px; height: 100%; border-right: solid 1px #e1e1e1;">
    I should be tall
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But the div doesn't get displayed with height being 100%. Why?

Comment: For an element to have a relative height it has to have a parent element with a specified size, for it's own size to be relative *to*. If you add `height: 500px;` (or whatever) to the `body` element it should work.

Comment: Here's a simple and clear explanation of the CSS `height` property with percentage values: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Answer (score 202, accepted):

You need to set a 100% height on all your parent elements, in this case your body and html. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5YHX7/3/) shows it working.

```css
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; }
div { height: 100%; width: 100%; background: #F52887; }
```

```html
<html><body><div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: The fiddle worked because it sets both html and body to 100% height.

Comment: and what about the width? we dont have to specify the parent's width? @EdBayiates

Comment: @Adamnick, the question was only about the height.  The width does not affect the height.

Comment: hi, thanks this works. can you explain why it is necessary to set the parent heights to 100%?

Answer (score 99):

Make it 100% of the viewport height:

```
div {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Works in all modern browsers and IE>=9, see here for [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window).

On some mobile browsers like Safari, the address bar will show/hide on scroll. To take this into account, use one of [`svh`, `lvh` or `dvh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#relative_length_units_based_on_viewport) (check [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=dvh)).

Comment: Be aware that it may not work as expected on mobile where 100vh doesn't take some UI elements of the browser into account. This is especially annoying when you put something at the bottom of 100vh tall element.

Answer (score 30):

`height: 100%` works if you give a fixed size to the parent element.

Answer (score 17):

You can achieve that by using positioning.

Try

```
position: absolute;
```

to get the 100% height.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 6):

You need to set 100% height on the parent element.

Answer (score 4):

Add height:100% to body

```
body{height:100%}
```

Comment: This did not work unless I also gave the 100% size to the HTML as @Jan shows.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need in the CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the root parent have to be in pixels if you want to work freely with percents,

```
<body style="margin: 0px; width: 1886px; height: 939px;">
<div id="containerA" class="containerA" style="height:65%;width:100%;">
    <div id="containerAinnerDiv" style="position: relative; background-color: aqua;width:70%;height: 80%;left:15%;top:10%;">
       <div style="height: 100%;width: 50%;float: left;"></div>
       <div style="height: 100%;width: 28%;float:left">
            <img src="img/justimage.png" style="max-width:100%;max-height:100%;">
       </div>
       <div style="height: 100%;width: 22%;float: left;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```