# Plugin with full screen

Tags: html, object, firebreath, browser-plugin

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to convince a browser to give me access to all available real estate within browser tap. I know that I load my plugin with the html object tag. Within that tag I would give the width and height for my plugin window.

So my question is: What are the common procedures to recreate my plugin window for the whole browser tab? I'm not really looking for complete full screen access but that would be nice to know, as well.

I'm using Firebreath as my plugin framework.

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Not sure what you mean by browser tap?

Answer (score 1):

While there might be [workarounds](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-elastic-videos) for doing that in-page (not sure myself), you may be looking for [full page plugins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Basics#Plug-in_display_modes).

Going into fullscreen (like e.g. Flash and game-engine plugins do) is something you have to implement yourself and you have the necessary access to the native APIs to do so.

Comment: True full screen, should you care to support it, requires that you actually create your own full-screen window.  You don't get direct access to the window (on any platform) that the browser uses, so as Georg suggested your only option would be to use CSS to make the plugin object tag take up all available real estate.

It can be done, but it's probably going to be a bit of a pain.  Look around at how full-window flash sites do it.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I don't think I want a full-page plugin since I don't want to create a MIME type. So, it seems that I need css to find out the available window size. Has anyone a link that would describe such procedure. Thanks!

Comment: I found the following links helpful: http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/quick-tip-css-100-height/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262852/css-height-in-percent-not-working