# ng-view height issue in angularJS?

Tags: css, angularjs

I am using ng-view, to display view based on the routeProvider. In my application, ng-view added like this

```
<div ng-view  style="height: 100%; background:#000000;"></div>.
```

In one of my views, there is a left navigation, which should displayed 100% in height in the browser.  For some reason, left view navigation height is created only based upon the data. That is if data is more, height is incremented.

[image]

I am not sure, why height is not incremented  even though I set hieght=100%, here is the code of Left navigation

```
<div class="options1"> 



 <div class="options"> 
         <a ng-repeat="name in list" >{{name.name}}</a>
    </div>

</div >

.options {
    background:#FFFFFF;

    min-height: 190px;

    width:10em;

    height:100%;

    border: 1px solid red;

    color:#FFFFFF;

}

.options1 {
    min-height:100%; 

    background:red;

    width:15em;


}`
```

Answer (score 4):

I got it working, it is an CSS issue.
I have added this into CSS,

html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; }.

Here is the link for more details

[Css height in percent not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262852/css-height-in-percent-not-working)

Answer (score 3):

use Viewport Height, it's absolutely

```
style="height: 100vh;"
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an angularJS issue, but most likely a CSS styling issue. If it is so, then you need to investigate it as such - there isn't much information to go on in your question, but a div stretches to 100% **of it's parent**, so you need to make sure that is happening. Also, positioning is very important.

If this is the case, there is no need to duplicate an answer - see if [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin) is of any help.

Comment: Ok, I have edited Question and added CSS. Please let me know if you need more info

Comment: The problem probably isn't with .options, or .options1.. check to see that the ng-view div is 100% height (as in, it really streches from top to bottom), and if not, consider that the problem must be in that div's parent.

Comment: ng-view is not taking 100%. That is the issue I think. here ng-view parent is <body>. so, if I give 100% for ng-view it should take height as 100% right!

Comment: wrong - you need to set body and html to height: 100%, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think css:

```
.ng-scope{
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

On my computer it works correctly,
for reference only