# Ensure div container stays at full height on vertical resize

Tags: html, css

This is my container:

```
.test {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

**update**: This actually works without problem in **firefox**.

Which stretches to the full height of the webpage whenever the page is loaded, **but** when I resize the page vertically, it seems the viewport is not updated. In this first image, the div is the full height of the viewport:

[image]

However, when I resize the browser window vertically, the `.test` div is not updated - see image below.

[image]

To see for yourself, please check out the codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CLbqy

Should I resize the window **horizontally** however, the height resets to the correct viewport height.

Comment: Well, in Chrome it doesn't even resize at all.

Comment: You're right, it seems like this is not a problem in Firefox at least.

Comment: I've researched a little bit into this now, so thank you =) `vh` and `vm` are actually new to me, although I see it applied much, much more with text rather than `<div />` structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possible suggestion is that you should use `%` instead `vw` or `vh`. Since we may not be able to give `font-size` in `%`, instead of px or em,  we can use `vw` or similar kind of stuff.

And now if fonts given in `vm` they will not load the new change of `window` `height` and `width` if re-sized. So here is a small solution which I found in some random article.

```
causeRepaintsOn = $("#yourTagIdWithFontInVM");

$(window).resize(function() {
  causeRepaintsOn.css("z-index", 1);
});
```

This is the link where I found the above solution. [Link](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Comment: I tried using 100% as well as the solution from the article, but I'm still encountering the same problem.

Comment: if you are using height see this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262852/css-height-in-percent-not-working

Comment: This worked! Setting body and html height to 100% did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with scrolling in the CodePen iframe. It worked better for me when I prevented the page from overflowing:

```
html, body  {
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that I'm afraid, and I'm still running into the same problem with my application (which doesn't use iframes).