# css Background_image property not working?

Tags: css, codeigniter

In css file of my **Code Igniter** project, if i try to include any image file as background then it is not working.
    Any one CodeIgniter expert please help me. How to make a **background-image(file name)** work in code Igniter.

Comment: What did you write? What do you see in the inspector & network tab?

Comment: probably something to do with paths, whats the path that appears to you when you inspect the page?

Answer (score 2):

What Ryan said is correct, just don't forget to put quotes (or single quotes) around the file name/location.

If this isn't the issue, could you provide the code that you have?

Comment: <div style="background-image:url("loginbackground.jpg" ); width:100%; height:100%;"></div> Dear Steve without codigniter it work perfectly but with codigniter whin I load this view it does'nt work

Comment: Two things. Firstly, use single quotes for the image in this case as this is inline styling. Secondly, you're using percentage values for width and height is also a problem here.

You can see more about problem #2 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262852/css-height-in-percent-not-working

Comment: thanks....my dear now I solve the problem.... below is the solution...
**background-image:url(<?php echo base_url("dashboard/img/transcript.jpg") ?>**

Answer (score 0):

CSS uses the following:

```
.your-class {
    background-image: url(file name);
}
```

Comment: thanks ...all specially Ryan Kinal.. I solved my problem below is snipp

Comment: **background-image:url(<?php echo base_url("dashboard/img/transcript.jpg") ?>**