# div resize according to browser window in height

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

http://boosterdomains.com/svoge/index_register_2.html
Hello friends, i am struggling with one problem.
Click in menu top right button, the yellow one.
It will open modal window.
everything is fine.
But what if clients window/browser horizontally is half and uses notebook without scroll? he will be unable to register.
My questions is, how to make:
modal window automatically resize vertically as browser window resizes. what i want is to run away from scrolling. how to make it?

Comment: if your using bootstrap it will be responsive.. thats the whole point of frameworks. Most users wont open the view model and then resize window.. i think your wasting your time on a issue which probably wont be noticed.

Comment: My opinion is that you should never insert code that will almost never help users. It will only slow down your application. Browser resize is one of these situations.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I can suggest you several options:

1. You can use fixed height for the modal window and change it with media query for different devices.
2. You can change it with JavaScript getting the window height after firing the resize event of the window object:

   ```
   window.addEventListener('resize', function (e) {
   // Your resize here.
   });
   ```
3. Read about how to use [height in percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262852/css-height-in-percent-not-working) and set it to something around 70-80%.

Comment: You can use fixed height for the modal window and change it with media query for different devices.
Yep, that's helped. I set max height on modal, and then use @media query max height. Now i think it looks much better.