# % height does not work as I expected

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a responsive div, which has a section and aside. The parent div occupies 25% height. And the child divs has to occupy 80% of the their parent container. But they are not occupying if the height is in %. But it works fine when the height is given in pixels. Can any one tell me where I went wrong.
Here is the html

```
<div class="container">

  <section>
    This is supposed to be a section
  </section>
  <aside>
    This is supposed to be aside

  </aside>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 25%;
}

.container::before,
.container::after{
  content: "";
  display: table;

}

.container::after{
  clear: both;
}

section{
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

aside{
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  height: 80%;
}

section, aside{
  background: green;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 5%;
}
```

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gvpmahesh/Lhpv0k2x/3/

Comment: There's no height to be inherited from `html` or `body`. Either give those a specific height (can be percentage) or use viewport units. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8262852/3168107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify height to body and html tags

https://jsfiddle.net/Lhpv0k2x/5/

```
body,html { height: 100%; }
```

### EDIT

I am not a `float` fan, but if you need to use it you can make this:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lhpv0k2x/9/

I edit that:

- `.container` vertical padding of 5% (to avoid the vertical margin in the elements)
- `section, aside` with margin only horizontal of 5%

And that's all

Comment: But why the floats are breaking away from the parent container even though we applied clearfix

Comment: That's the space, I can edit the fiddle to show how to fix

Comment: You can remove the div tag with the clearfix. And I don't understand the vertical padding, vertical align in your code. Can you please explain a bit.

Comment: Yes, the clearfix was a test but that's not the solution. With the padding in the container you can separate the elements. If you put a height with 100% and margin of 5% (top and bottom), the total height will be 110% and it's because the box goes out of the container.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `position: relative; height: 100%;` on the parent elements, i.e. `html` and `body`.

You also need to apply `position: relative;` for any elements you want to use % height on.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vdy82azk/

**EDIT:** `position: relative;` is not necessary on *every* element. (see somethinghere's comment)

Comment: Thats not true - you do not need to define position to use percentage based heights, its just that all the parent tags needs to have a height defined, be it in percentage or pixels. (remove positioning from your fiddle changes nothing, for example)

Comment: @somethinghere is right. The clearfix is not breaking, it's just that the height is explicitly defined, and the content happens to flow out of the container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put something like this:

```
 html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;

            }
.container{
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 25%;
}

.container::before,
.container::after{
  content: "";
  display: table;

}

.container::after{
  clear: both;
}

section{
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  height: 80%;
  display: block;
}

aside{
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  height: 80%;
}

section, aside{
  background: green;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin:5%;
}
```

Link:

```
 https://jsfiddle.net/1utwx2fp/
```