# CSS: Few questions about position absolute

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, absolute

I've got a few questions about position: absolute centered elements. I was looking on almost every position absolute articles, but didn't find something that would explain me this strange behaviour that I am now asking about. Here is codepen that relates to the questions(expect third question): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LQrjzz

1. Why does div jump down, when changed div width units from px to percentage(40px = 12.2%) How can I fix this, if I want to use percentage?
2. Why does div jump down, when resizing a window even when there is still space(https://i.imgur.com/4DPu9Vp.gifv)? How can I fix this?
3. Why in this snippet second div's height = 0? I've expected its height to be 50px as width.

```css
main{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#first{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}

#second{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="second"></div>
</main>
```

//code from codepen

HTML:

```
<main>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
main{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 2px red solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

h1{
  font-size: 32px;
  width: 10em;
  border: 2px black dotted;
}

p{
  font-size: 32px;
  width: 10em;
  border: 2px green dotted;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px; /*  12.2%  */
  height: 40px;
  background: lawngreen;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 2px blue dotted;
}
```

I hope those questions weren't dumb. Thank you very much.

Comment: second div height is 0 because it is 50% of main which does not have a height set - [see this for explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262852/css-height-in-percent-not-working)

Comment: @Pete Neither width is not. Why width have different results than height?

Comment: width and height are not the same ... width is by default 100% and height bu default auto

Comment: I think the percentage thing is caused because it will probably draw the main container first so that it can calculate the width of the percentage width child.  As it does this, it will keep that original width and drop the square down as both the div and p are inline block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## *Why does div jump down, when changed div width units from px to percentage(40px = 12.2%) How can I fix this, if I want to use percentage?*

Your `div` is in a container that has no defined width. Since the `div` itself can change the width of the container, CSS cannot resolve a width set as a percentage. To solve that depends on what is your actual goal...

## *Why does div jump down, when resizing a window even when there is still space? How can I fix this?*

By default, `left, right, bottom, top` are set to `auto`. The width of your container is set by its content, but `auto` on a side property means *"the value of `right` cannot be lower than `0`."* So, since your `left` is set to `50%` and `right` to `auto` (default), it is equivalent to setting `max-width` to `50%`: your container cannot take more than 50% of it relative parent width.

Here a GIF to help you visualize what's happening:

[image: DIV resize based on right auto]

To solve that, you need another wrapper and a different centering trick such as `inline-block` content:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
}

html {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/**
 new element
 */
.center{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width : 100%;
  font-size : 0;
  text-align:center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/**
 center with inline block
 */
main{
  display:inline-block;
  font-size : 1rem;
  border: 2px red solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

h1{
  font-size: 32px;
  width: 10em;
  border: 2px black dotted;
}

p{
  font-size: 32px;
  width: 10em;
  border: 2px green dotted;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.block{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px; /*  12.2%  */
  height: 40px;
  background: lawngreen;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 2px blue dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <main>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </main>
</div>
```

## *Why in this snippet second div's height = 0? I've expected its height to be 50px as width.*

This occurs for the exact same reason as question #1. Again, we need to know your final goal to further help you achieve what you want here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I dont understand your second answer though. I don't change value of right, do I? In your snippet, center container takes 100% of its parent and you wrote this: "your container cannot take more than 50% of it relative parent width." What am I getting wrong?

Comment: That one is kinda hard to explain... You do not change the value, but the default value is `auto`, which mean the value cannot be lower than 0. My snippet is a working code, it is a way to remove the limitation of a centered element with absolute positioning.

Comment: Hey again. Your second answer is not correct. It was because of ```transform: translate(-50%, -50%);```. I will post a answer.

Comment: @J.Doe `translate` doesn't affect the width of the element, by removing the transform property, you can actually better see what I'm trying to explain. Well, might be the language barrier, but I'm sorry that I cannot explain the problem easily... which is not the `transform` itself.

Comment: I tried to show it in a video: https://imgur.com/a/I9TFL. The right border is the equivalent of `right:0;`. Since the default value is `auto` (value cannot be lower than 0), the div resize when it reaches the side. `translate` doesn't change the computed position.

Comment: Yes I understand it now. Could you please edit your answer and add this gif to your answer? I am marking your asnwer as solution. :)